# Problem with projection in OpenLayers3

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, geojson

I would like to add polygon geojson in the `EPSG:2178` projection. The polygon should be displayed in central Europe but I see my geojson in Asia. 
Where have I made a mistake? Where can I find information about `ol.View "center"`?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ol.css'>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
    <script src="build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
           }),

   new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
         projection : 'EPSG:2178',
         url: 'gjson/eg.geojson'
      })
  })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center:[0,0],
          zoom:2

        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should update your ol version, `ol.source.GeoJSON`  doesn't exist anymore see [the new example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html)

Second if you want that your coordinates are automatically transformed to the map projection system (by default it's `EPSG:3857`), you need to include `Proj4js` librairy and the definition of your projection:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="//epsg.io/2178.js"></script>
```

Finally, if you are stuck with this version of OpenLayers, the definiton of your `ol.source.GeoJSON` should be :

```
new ol.source.GeoJSON({
  defaultProjection : 'EPSG:2178',
  projection : 'EPSG:3857', // This is the destination projection not the data projection
  url: 'gjson/eg.geojson'
})
```

See the [ol.source.GeoJSON doc](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.source.GeoJSON.html?unstable=true)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stil it doesn't work . I dont know why . I put sample of geojson data and my script http://www.speedyshare.com/r8ahx/egib.geojson. I was workin on sample of data :https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=V6IbjQ1Jn0 but it is wrong

Comment: here I made this in other way but I only see a map not geojson: http://jsfiddle.net/zzahmbff/146/#&togetherjs=KTokvnMLsm